# Extjs - Multi validations VType email

Tags: extjs

I've a probllem with email textfield on which I want to perform multi validations. In detail:
    1. Classic format email validation
    2. Unique email check

Can I override email VType? or I have to create a custom VType? How can I perform two validation with two different error messages in a single VType?

```
Thanks
Regards
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override the default validation using the `validator` attribute.  For example, if you wish to enforce the standard rules *and* some other rules (e.g. defined by `isSomeOtherRules()` that returns a boolean), set the following attribute:

```
validator: function(value) {
    return Ext.form.VTypes.email(value) && isSomeOtherRules(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Andrew's post; we can return validation messages (shown below) to get the same look and feel of vtype error alert:

```
               validator: function(value) {
                    if (!Ext.form.VTypes.cfpValidatePdf(value)) {
                        return 'File must be pdf';
                    } else if (!Ext.form.VTypes.cfpValidateFileNameSize(value)) {
                        return 'The maximum length of the filename is 64';
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```